# Why 2 Controller Name appear in uri segment 1 at codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i code `href="<?= base_url(loket/index_pos_bakum) ?>"` then run it, it run normali. im directed to base_url/loket/index_pos_bakum. but the problem comes when i type code like before with deffrent value, base_url(admin/loket_admin). it doesnt gonna redirect to admin/loket_admin but its redirect to base_url/loket/admin/loket_admin. the first controller name always appear when im gonna try to redirect to any controller.

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Loket extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index_pos_bakum()
  {
    $data['loket'] = $this->db->get_where('nomor_antrian', ['id_loket' => 0])->result_array();
    $data['antrian'] = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(nomor) AS nomor FROM nomor_antrian WHERE id_loket = 0 ")->row_array();
    $this->template->load('template', 'operator/v_pos_yankum', $data);
  }
}
```

And this is my second controller

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Admin_model', 'a_model');
  }

  public function loket_admin()
  {

    $this->template->load('template','admin/index_loket');
  }
```

Comment: is Admin controller inside folder "loket" ? if not then call it by http://myipserver:myport/myapp/admin/loket_admin

Comment: no. all controller file at controller folder @ni3solanki

Comment: then try to access by : http://myipserver:myport/myapp/admin/loket_admin

Comment: sure it works, but when I use href or button it doesn't work. loket controller always appear in Uri segment 1 even i only type base_url(admin/loket_admin) @ni3solanki